# WSUS moved how to reset the database and check the folders?

Tags: windows-server-2008, wsus

I have a bit of a problem with a WSUS box, I backed up the WsusContent folder (about 180 gig) to a second machine, wiped the first machine then realized I don't have the database folder! I can not find any articles / guidance on this, I have re installed WSUS however it does not find the other files which where previsously downloaded (I guess the database being the reason). If I do a reset it will force it to download the ones it has again I guess and does not check what is still to be downloaded?

Sigh... love / hate WSUS at the moment with a passion :)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This is becoming a race between getting a response from someone on stack overflow and my WSUS box downloading the packages again! :D

Comment: Looks like I am going to have to open a bounty! :(

Comment: your better off starting fresh.

Comment: Looks like it, I am currently back up to 80 gig... so.. shame really.

Answer (score 2):

Did you do an `export` when you "backed up" the WsusContent folder?  This will then have created a cab file that you could have imported into your new server (which would create the database when you reinstall) `wsusutil.exe import c:\path\to\wsuscontent\cabfile.cab log.txt` If you did not do an export of your data I don't believe you will have a cab file to import that data back.  The `reset` command will check the update metadata in your database to the corresponding update files that are stored in WsusContent to check if they are missing or corrupt.  If so, it will download them again.

Comment: Hi, no I didn't :( I just copied the files. Thanks for the response though.

Comment: @MatthewZielonka.co.uk unfortunately then your sorta screwed since you wiped the server.  Next time, do an export so it will save off your cab file (metadata) and then copy all your data files and cab file off to the second sever.